# combine multiple outputs in python

Tags: python

I am a noob and was wondering how to combine multiple outputs into one string that outputs

Here is my code

```
print  ("password size (use numbers)")
  
  passwordsize = int(input(""))
  passwordsize = passwordsize -1
  papers = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','?','!','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',]

  q_list = [random.choice(papers) for i in range(passwordsize)]
  ' '.join(q_list)
  poopers = q_list[0].replace("'", '')
  print("/")
  print(q_list)
  

  for word in q_list:
    result = word.replace("'", '')
    print(result)
```

lets say that the random stuff picked was `3 a b c`
it outputs...

```
3
a
b
c
```

I want it to output...
`3abc`
Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: `q_list=''.join(q_list)` and you're good to go

Comment: Replace `print(result)` to `print(result, end='')`. Python `print` will output `\n` in the end because of the default value of `end` is `\n`, so you should manually define it if you don't want to change to a new line. Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

```py
import random

passwordsize = 4 # int(input("")) - 1
papers = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T',
          'U','V','W','X','Y','Z','?','!','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',]
q_list = [random.choice(papers) for i in range(passwordsize)]

result = ""
for word in q_list:
    result += word
print(result)
```

String object in python can use add "+" operation to do concatenation.
For example, if you want to create `s = "ABC"`, you can create it by `s = 'A' + 'B' + 'C'`.
The `+=` operation can iteratively do the `+` operation.
Thus, you can create `"ABC"` by a for loop:

```
s = ""
for w in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
    s += w
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 1):

Along the same lines as what @Chuck and @Ash proposed, but streamlining things a bit by taking fuller advantage of Python's standard library as well as the handy `join` string method:

```
import random
import string

passwordsize = 4 # int(input()) - 1
a = [*string.ascii_uppercase, *string.digits, "?", "!"]
print("".join(random.sample(a, passwordsize)))
```

Output:

```
W16H
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want every generated char is unique, use `random.sample`. But if you want every char can occur more than one, use `random.choices` instead:

```
from random import choices; from string import ascii_uppercase as caps, digits as nums
result = ''.join(choices(caps+'?!'+nums,k=int(input('password size (use numbers)\n'))))
print(result)

# password size (use numbers)
# 15
# DK6V1DZOFKA?3HG
```